# Java: Difference between Java Hotspot Server Compiler and Client Compiler

Tags: java, jvm, compiler-optimization

Today, when i was reading about `Escape Analysis` in `JVM` from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html. In this, they discuss about `Java Hotspot Server Compiler`. I am confuse what is `Server Compiler` in Java. I was also Google about this, some where they use `Java Hotspot Client Compiler`. I am still not catch, what actually the server and client compilers are?. Is server compiler is different from normal JDK or it is the part of JVM?

Comment: it's when you run java with the `-server` flag.

Comment: @assylias - I think the OP is confused because they use the term *compiler* and not *JIT compiler* explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are talking about the JIT (Just-in-Time) compiler in the Hotspot VM.

> J**ava Hotspot Client Compiler** - is usually used for client environments
>   (less processing)
>
> Provides improved runtime performance for applications and applets.
>   The Java HotSpot Client VM has been specially tuned to reduce
>   application start-up time and memory footprint, making it particulary
>   well suited for client environments.
>
> **Java Hotspot Server Compiler**
>    The Java HotSpot Server VM is similar
>   to the Java HotSpot Client VM, except that it has been specially tuned
>   to maximize peak operating speed. It is intended for running
>   long-running server applications, for which having the fastest
>   possible operating speed is generally more important than having the
>   fastest possible start-up time.

Check [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs343/resources/java-hotspot.pdf) and [this](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/~Francois.Faure/enseignement/ressources/java/jdk1.3/guide/performance/hotspot.html) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Hello @TheLostMind, my main question is that, These are the parts of JVM or JDK. They use internally by JVM, or user user these machines for special?

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara - They are part of the JVM

Comment: These are used by JVM not direct user interact with this. According to your answer, `They are talking about the JIT (Just-in-Time) compiler` it mean these are the part of JIT?

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara - JIT compiler comes in 2 flavors, client and server